# A logical data model that allows users to edit data and approvers to approve or reject changes

Tags: data-modeling, tracking

As it says on the title, I have a project that needs to do just that. How do I implement the logical data model?

The actual nature of the data is not important. Let's say I am building a school database, and teachers can update a student's scores and other details. Once updated these will be stored in the database, but the changes will wait for the headteacher to approve or reject them.

Bear in mind that a teacher can make a number of changes in a session, e.g. changing a John's address, then entering Sally's latest math score and finally updating next month's timetable. The headteacher, upon logging on, should see a series of unapproved changes, go through them one by one, and approve or reject.

Assume that once Mr Jones has changed Sally's math score from 90 to 88, that change is visible only to Mr Jones and the headteacher. Everybody else will still see 90. Mrs Smith is allowed to still make more change to Sally's official score (90), so it's possble that when the headteacher logs in, s/he will see two updates:

1. Mr Jones' update from 90 to 88.
2. Mrs Smith's update from 90 to 85.

The headteacher will know which came after which and decide which to update and which to reject.

Thanks in advance.

**PS.** I'd especially like to know if any pattern is already available in the public domain.

Comment: There are *a lot* of ways to do this and also many open questions. Can a teacher make consecutive changes to a student? If so is the change based on the "official" state or on the state that is yet unapproved? In the latter case, is it like this only for the teacher that suggested the change? And so on and so forth... The complexity can be extremely high or held to a minimum.

Comment: I have updated the question with some assumptions.

Comment: If you really are creating the *logical* data model, then all you have to do is properly identify the nouns in your requirements. Make each noun a relation and define its primary key. If you do that, then I don't see how you can fail. If, however, you are supposed to physicalize the model, then you might have plenty of other things to consider. The relationship between nouns (relations), the verbs in your requirements, will dictate the cardinality of each end of a relationship.

Comment: Looks like git (or any other version control software) or some transactional database.

Answer (score 1):

I way to do it create a control table. Which will store all the approval details. Only head master will be able to add row in control table.

Also, create a staging table to store user inputs till final decision.  This table should be visible to only users with update/insert access.

In your main table,  create a trigger to insert data from staging to main table, whenever headmaster makes a commit.